# Making an array for a static casted indexed array

Tags: c++, arrays, static-cast

I don't know if my title is right but I am trying to eliminate duplicate so I think I should put this definitions in an array. Can someone suggest me how I could put the pButtons in array? I am thinking something like pButton[EButtonHost], pButton[EButtonUsername] etc.

```
#define pButtonHost static_cast<XQtMultipleStringInputButton*>(m_pButtonList[EButtonHost])
#define pButtonUsername static_cast<XQtMultipleStringInputButton*>(m_pButtonList[EButtonUsername])
#define pButtonPassword static_cast<XQtMultipleStringInputButton*>(m_pButtonList[EButtonPassword])
```

I have a method below like this.

```
XIniFile readIniFile;
readIniFile.open(k_systemIniFile, EIniReadOnly);

string data;

readIniFile.readString("Server", "host", data);
pButtonHost->setString(data);
m_host = pButtonHost->getString();

readIniFile.readString("Server", "username", data);
pButtonUsername->setString(data);
m_username = pButtonUsername->getString();

readIniFile.readString("Server", "password", data);
pButtonPassword->setString(data);
m_password = pButtonPassword->getString();
```

They look like duplicates so I am trying to optimize it. Thanks!

Update:
I have something like this now. Would this be right? or do you have any better suggestions?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    readIniFile.readString("Server", k_dataList[i], data);
    static_cast<XQtMultipleStringInputButton*>(m_pButtonList[i])->setString(data);
    m_pData[i] = static_cast<XQtMultipleStringInputButton*>(m_pButtonList[i])->getString();
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you intend to have something like this one?

```
#define ASIZE 3
int indx[ASIZE] = {EButtonHost, EButtonUsername, EButtonPassword};
string s[ASIZE] = {"host", "username", "password"};
string *m[ASIZE] = {&m_host, &m_username, &m_password};

for (int i = 0; i < ASIZE; i++) {
  readIniFile.readString("Server", s[i].c_str(), data);
  pButtonHost->setString(data);
  *m[i] = pButtonHost->getString();
}
```

Comment: @Gibs Accept the ans?

Answer (score 2):

A below code looks clear by using `auto` and `lambda',

```
auto GetConfigInfo = [&](string section_name, ButtonType btn_type)-> string
{
    readIniFile.readString("Server", section_name, data);
    m_pButtonList[btn_type_]->setString(data);
    return m_pButtonList->getString();
};

m_host      = GetConfigInfo("host",     EButtonHost);
m_username  = GetConfigInfo("username", EButtonUserName);
m_password  = GetConfigInfo("password", EButtonPassword);
```

and a define data type by using struct can be other method.

```
struct ConfigDefine
{
    string  section_;
    ButtonType btn_type_; //your enum button type, such as EButtonHost, EButtonUserName
    string& result_;

}configs[]  = 
{
    {"host",     EButtonHost,     m_host},
    {"username", EButtonUserName, m_username},
    {"password", EButtonPassword, m_password}
};

for_each(std::begin(configs), std::end(configs), [&](ConfigDefine& config)
{
    readIniFile.readString("Server", config.section_, data);
    m_pButtonList[config.btn_type_]->setString(data);
    config.result_ = pButtonHost->getString();

});
```